# What in my code changed between MacTeX 2017 and MacTex 2019?

Tags: todonotes

I have upgraded from MacTeX 2017 to 2019 and I have this problem that I can\t figure out. Consider:

```
\documentclass[article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[textsize=small, linecolor=magenta, bordercolor=magenta,
            backgroundcolor=magenta, textwidth=4cm]{todonotes}

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\@todonotes@drawMarginNoteWithLine}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, baseline=-0.75ex]%
        \node [coordinate] (inText) {};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \marginpar[{% Draw note in left margin
        \@todonotes@drawMarginNote{r}%
        \@todonotes@drawLineToLeftMargin%
    }]{% Draw note in right margin
        \@todonotes@drawMarginNote{l}%
        \@todonotes@drawLineToRightMargin%
    }%
    }
    \renewcommand{\@todonotes@drawMarginNote}[1]{
        \makebox[\marginparwidth][#1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,baseline=(X.base)]%
            \node(X){\vphantom{X}};%
            \draw node[notestyle,font=\@todonotes@sizecommand,anchor=north] (inNote) at (X.north)%
                {\@todonotes@text};%
            \if@todonotes@authorgiven%
                \draw node[notestyle,font=\@todonotes@sizecommand,anchor=north] (inNote) at (X.north)%
                    {\@todonotes@sizecommand\@todonotes@author};%
                \node(Y)[below=of X]{};%
                \draw node[notestyle,font=\@todonotes@sizecommand,anchor=north] (inNote) at (X.south)%
                    {\@todonotes@text};%
            \else%
                \draw node[notestyle,font=\@todonotes@sizecommand,anchor=north] (inNote) at (X.north)%
                    {\@todonotes@text};%
            \fi%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }}
\makeatother

\LetLtxMacro{\oldtodo}{\todo}
\renewcommand{\todo}[1]{{\color{magenta}\oldtodo[fancyline]{\color{white}\textsf{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
Lorem \todo{Test} ipsum\ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am sure the text "small" was not there in black before the upgrade. It is supposed to be the text size of the todo comment...

What has gone wrong / changed?

Comment: I filed a bug report.

Answer (score 7):

An update to `todonotes.sty` introduced a regression: the code

```latex
\define@key{todonotes.sty}%
    {textsize}{\renewcommand{\@todonotes@textsize}{\csname #1\endcsname}}
```

became

```latex
\define@key{todonotes.sty}%
    {textsize}{\renewcommand{\@todonotes@textsize}{#1}}
\define@key{todonotes.sty}%
    {size}{\renewcommand{\@todonotes@textsize}{#1}}
```

which is the cause for the appearance of “small”.

Workaround:

```latex
\documentclass[article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[linecolor=magenta, bordercolor=magenta,
            backgroundcolor=magenta, textwidth=4cm]{todonotes}

\makeatletter
\define@key{todonotes.sty}%
    {textsize}{\renewcommand{\@todonotes@textsize}{\csname#1\endcsname}}
\define@key{todonotes.sty}%
    {size}{\renewcommand{\@todonotes@textsize}{\csname#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother
\setkeys{todonotes.sty}{textsize=small}


\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\@todonotes@drawMarginNoteWithLine}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, baseline=-0.75ex]%
        \node [coordinate] (inText) {};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \marginpar[{% Draw note in left margin
        \@todonotes@drawMarginNote{r}%
        \@todonotes@drawLineToLeftMargin%
    }]{% Draw note in right margin
        \@todonotes@drawMarginNote{l}%
        \@todonotes@drawLineToRightMargin%
    }%
    }
    \renewcommand{\@todonotes@drawMarginNote}[1]{%
        \makebox[\marginparwidth][#1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,baseline=(X.base)]%
            \node(X){\vphantom{X}};%
            \draw node[notestyle,font=\@todonotes@sizecommand,anchor=north] (inNote) at (X.north)%
                {\@todonotes@text};%
            \if@todonotes@authorgiven%
                \draw node[notestyle,font=\@todonotes@sizecommand,anchor=north] (inNote) at (X.north)%
                    {\@todonotes@sizecommand\@todonotes@author};%
                \node(Y)[below=of X]{};%
                \draw node[notestyle,font=\@todonotes@sizecommand,anchor=north] (inNote) at (X.south)%
                    {\@todonotes@text};%
            \else%
                \draw node[notestyle,font=\@todonotes@sizecommand,anchor=north] (inNote) at (X.north)%
                    {\@todonotes@text};%
            \fi%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }}
\makeatother

\LetLtxMacro{\oldtodo}{\todo}
\renewcommand{\todo}[1]{{\color{magenta}\oldtodo[fancyline]{\color{white}\textsf{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
Lorem \todo{Test} ipsum\ldots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue was caused by the commit:  https://github.com/henrikmidtiby/todonotes/commit/f181263dda919c52f23a4b62dae13d571185144f
where the way the textsize command was stored was changed to accept two different values like `\small` and the string `small` as values for the size option in the todo command.

As an example take the document below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
This\todo[fancyline]{Test}
is a\todo[fancyline, size=Huge]{Test}
very simple test\todo[fancyline, size=\tiny]{Test}.
\end{document}
```

When the value in the fontsize should be used, it now required the use of the `\@todonotes@useSizeCommand`. I assume that will fix the issues.
So everytime you have used `\@todonotes@sizecommand` it should be replaced with `\@todonotes@useSizeCommand`.

I'm sorry that it has broken your existing code, but I had not imagined that usecase when the change was tested.

Comment: Aha, I understand. IMHO it makes sense.